# can't fix ExpressPeerServer is not a function in server.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webrtc, backend

I am stuck in a error where I have successfully installed peer.js library in my npm project but in my server.js file, when I try to import peer library and use it as a function, it is saying that peerServer is not a function.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express()
const server = require("http").Server(app);
const {v4:uuidv4} = require("uuid")
const io = require("socket.io")(server);
const peerServer = require("peer");
const ExpressPeerServer = peerServer(server, {
    debug: true,
})

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get("/", (req, res)=>{
    res.redirect(`/${uuidv4()}`)
})
app.get('/:room', (req, res)=>{
   res.render('room', {roomId : req.params.room})
})

server.listen(3000, ()=>{
    console.log("Server is running on port 3000")
})
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setup peerJS server combined with express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26712426/setup-peerjs-server-combined-with-express)

Comment: The docs of peer say:
 
`const peerServer = PeerServer({ port: 9000, path: '/myapp' }); ` so captital P

Answer (score 0):

From the [Peer readme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/peer).

```js
const { PeerServer } = require('peer');
```